# Why use tape for restoring AIX mksysb instead of other ordinary drive devices?

Tags: backup, aix, restore, tape

I'm intrigued by the fact that the only way to restore a mksysb backup on AIX Unix systems can be done either by using a NIM server or by manually using a tape.

Why is it that you cannot replace the tape and restore the mksysb using another disk drive, a flash drive or even a DVD?

Comment: I assume you're talking about a system-level restore and not a file-level restore?

Comment: Yes @JeffSchaller, the mksysb on AIX is a system-level restore

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if we can answer the "why" behind the "what", but your system restoration options are limited to what the System Management Services (SMS) can boot from. There is an old article: [Restore via a CD (Power5)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/POWER5/iphbm_p5/iphbm_update_profiles.htm) that steps you through restoring via a CD-ROM. Otherwise, the [typical SMS boot options](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/example-using-sms-choose-boot-device) are:

> 1. Diskette
> 2. Tape
> 3. CD/DVD
> 4. IDE
> 5. Hard Drive
> 6. Network

Of course, to use any of those, you must get the bootable image onto that media. Writing to a tape or a networked NIM server are common ways to do that.